# MJPEG Stream Freezes on First Frame since Firefox 49

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, html5-canvas

Starting from Firefox 49 and onwards, MJPEG stream from IP cameras freeze on the first frame using an in-house service. This does not occur in Chrome. I could not find any changes in the FF 49 changelog that might cause this error. Keep in mind, this code is not mine and is VERY old, but it still works in Chrome just fine.
Pieces of code I thought might cause the error:

```
CameraplayerUI.js
self.drawStream = function (image) {
            //#region Argument validation and sanitization

            if (typeof image === "undefined" || image === null) { return false; }
            if (typeof image.src === "undefined" || image.src === null) { return false; }
            if (!image.complete) { return false; }

            if (_stream.width !== image.width) { _stream.width = image.width; }

            if (_stream.height !== image.height) { _stream.height = image.height; }

            //#region Argument validation and sanitization

            if(_isLive !== true){
                _isLive = true;
                $(_image).hide();
                $(_stream).show();
            }

            _ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, _stream.width, _stream.height);
            self.source = image.src;
            return true;

/** Mjpegstream.js
         * Updates the current stream based on the elapsed time since last update.
         * Warning: Numeric representations for all parameters are used without validation for
         *          performance considerations.
         *
         * @param {Integer} time        - Current time}
         * @param {Integer} elapsedTime - Elapsed time since last update cycle.
         */
        this.update = function (time, elapsedTime) {
            if (!self.isOpen) { return false; }

            //#region Argument validation and sanitization

            time = +time; // Unary plus operation. Numeric representation.
            elapsedTime = +elapsedTime; // Unary plus operation. Numeric representation.

            //#endregion Argument validation and sanitization

            _serviceReauthenticationTimer = _serviceReauthenticationTimer - elapsedTime;
            if (_serviceReauthenticationTimer <= 0) {
                downloadAsync(_userId, _userKey, this.cameraId, update_callback);
            }

            // Firefox MJPEG stream fix.
             if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
                if (this.data !== "undefined" && this.data !== null) {

                    self.data.src = _stream.src;

                }
            }

            return true;
        };

Cameraplayer.js
if (self.isLive) {
                _time = now;
                ui.setTime(_time);

                if (!_mjpegStream.isAuthenticated) {
                    ui.showAuthenticationNotification(false, _mjpegStream.error);
                    self.hasError = true;
                } else if (_mjpegStream.error !== null) {
                    ui.showError(true, _mjpegStream.error);
                    self.hasError = true;
                } else if (_mjpegStream.isOpen) {
                    ui.clearNotifications();
                    if (_mjpegStream.isPlaying) {
                        if (_mjpegStream.update(_time, elapsedTime)) {
                            ui.drawStream(_mjpegStream.data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        _mjpegStream.play();
                    }
                } else if (_mjpegStream.isConnecting) {
                    ui.showLoading(true);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ui.showLoading(true);
                    _mjpegStream.open(_request);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                _time = time;
```

Keep in mind this program is huge and I just took snippets that I thought MAY cause the error. It works on all Firefox versions before 49 and currently on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on a [chrome bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74779).

According to [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3) :

> ... when a CanvasImageSource object represents an animated image in an HTMLOrSVGImageElement, the user agent must use the default image of the animation (the one that the format defines is to be used when animation is not supported or is disabled), or, if there is no such image, the first frame of the animation, when rendering the image for CanvasRenderingContext2D APIs.

MJPEG streams are part of these *animated image* and thus UAs must return only the first frame. Chrome lately followed this part of the specs, but **only** for GIF images.

So there is still the workaround of forcing a full reload of your MJPEG stream, by adding a random parameter in the request at each redraw, but you'll loose all the advantages of MJPEG format and make a lot of heavy requests.

```js
var url = 'http://webcam.st-malo.com/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=352x288';

var img = new Image();
img.onload = drawAndReload;
// check if there are already parameters in the passed url
var paramHead = url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?';
img.src = url;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

function drawAndReload(){
  if(c.width !== this.naturalWidth){
    c.width = this.naturalWidth;
    c.height = this.naturalHeight;
    }
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  // reset the image
  this.src = ''; // should not be necessary
  this.src = url + paramHead + Math.random(); // force no-cache
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

A real solution would be to convert your MJPEG stream to a video stream server-side, then use the [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) API to fetch the chunks and display it in an HTMLVideoElement, that you'll be able to draw on canvas without restrictions.